# Possibilities Array's (swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

How can i use more values of an array in a swift statement?

code:

```
var array = ["Beer", "Water", "Cola", "Sprite", "Wodka"]

var drinks = "" // The variable drinks updates with a pickerView of the above array

func doSomethingWithArray() {

    if drinks == array[1] {

        print("this is water, so no sugar in it")

    } else if drinks == array[2,3] {

        print("This drink contains sugar")

    } else {
        print("This drink is alcoholic")
}
```

Is there an easy way to use multiple array values like in the else if statement? but a way that works then. :)

Comment: Do you want to check if `doSomething` (Why does this variable have a *verb* name? Variables are things, *nouns*.) is one of those elements?

Comment: Bad example , will edit the question, sorry

Comment: What do you need this for, anyway? picking random indices like that is a codesmell

Comment: I don't think anyone here get is... but can't you just user `else` instead of `else if doSomething == array[0,2,3]`?

Comment: ok wait, will edit it again so you'll see i can't just use else :)

Comment: @adam.s you'd be better off making a "drink" struct, which has a boolean property "has sugar", and then storing a `Dictionary` associating those `Drink` structs with their names

Comment: edited again :) and yes maybe, that's an option, but i thought if this worked it was a pretty easy solution :)

Comment: You can do: `else if doSomething == array[0] || doSomething == array[2]...`, or a switch

Comment: @totoajax That was indeed an option; one i already knew but thx anyway :D i just wanted it to be smaller code, or i hoped it would be possible to make the code smaller.

Comment: @adams.s Don't misuse arrays like this. All it takes is one addition into the middle of the array to break all your program logic.

Comment: How do you mean one addition? Do you mean like making an array of multiple arrays? An array for the none sugar types, array for the alcoholic drinks and an array for the sugar drinks?

Comment: So i just have to order them in the array and then use like array[1...3] or something? Sorry pretty new in this

Comment: @adam.s Haveyou heard of Structs and Dictionaries before?

Comment: yes.. i've learned it. Maybe i should grab my books again and try it with a struct or dictionary...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following the conversation in the comments, this code should work

```
struct Drink {
    var name: String
    var haveSugar: Bool
    var haveAlcohol: Bool

    init (name: String, haveSugar: Bool, haveAlcohol: Bool) {
        self.name = name
        self.haveSugar = haveSugar
        self.haveAlcohol = haveAlcohol
    }
}

var drinks = [Drink(name: "Beer", haveSugar: true, haveAlcohol: true), Drink(name: "Water", haveSugar: false, haveAlcohol: false), Drink(name: "Sprite", haveSugar: true, haveAlcohol: false), Drink(name: "Wodka", haveSugar: true, haveAlcohol: true)]

func checkDrink(drink: Drink) {
    if drink.haveSugar == true {
        print("\(drink.name) have sugar!")
    }
    else {
        print("\(drink.name) doesn't have sugar")
    }
}

checkDrink(drinks[1])
```

Comment: thx, worked perfectly, just one question.. image you have an array drinks, and the first drink is 10cl, the second 20, the third 40, fifth 100,.... and then you have to say like well, the one of 10 isn't much, the ones with 20 til 40 are enough, the ones with 100cl are plenty, the ones with 200 are too much...

Comment: @adams.s I'm not sure I get it, but as I do; yes

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you question correctly, this is the case where you could use `contains`.

```
let myDrink = "Cola"
let sweetDrinks = ["Cola", "Sprite"]

if sweetDrinks.contains(myDrink) {
    print(myDrink, "is a sweet drink")
}
```

To make more sophisticated checks, use Set. For example:

```
let myDrinks = Set(["Beer", "Water", "Cola", "Vodka", "Tonic"])
let sweetDrinks = ["Cola", "Sprite", "Tonic"]

// Show myDrinks which are also sweet drinks
let mySweetDrinks = myDrinks.intersect(sweetDrinks)
print(mySweetDrinks) // prints ["Tonic", "Cola"]
```

Comment: That's also an option! Good thinking! Thx!